# Is it safe to cast ObjC id<Protocol> and typed objects to C pointer (void *) then cast it back?

Tags: objective-c, c, casting, metal

I'm working on C wrappers/bindings for Metal API (http://github.com/recp/cmtl).

I defined Objective-C types as void in C headers like `typedef void MtDevice`. Then I'm casting object allocated in ObjC function to **void*** pointer. Then casting it back to ObjC to call ObjC function.

Here my code[s]:

ARC style:

```
MtDevice*
mtDeviceCreat() {
  id<MTLDevice> mdevice;
  mdevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
  return (void *)CFBridgingRetain(mdevice);
}

MtCommandQueue*
mtCommandQueue(MtDevice *device) {
  id<MTLDevice>       mdevice;
  id<MTLCommandQueue> mcmdQueue;

  mdevice   = (__bridge id<MTLDevice>)device;
  mcmdQueue = [mdevice newCommandQueue];

  return (void *)CFBridgingRetain(mcmdQueue);
}
```

ARC-disabled:

```
MtDevice*
mtDeviceCreat() {
  id<MTLDevice> mdevice;
  mdevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
  return [mdevice retain];
}

MtCommandQueue*
mtCommandQueue(MtDevice *device) {
  id<MTLDevice>       mdevice;
  id<MTLCommandQueue> mcmdQueue;

  mdevice   = (__strong id<MTLDevice>)device;
  mcmdQueue = [mdevice newCommandQueue];

  return [mcmdQueue retain];
}
```

I'm considering to disable ARC, so I converted it to second version. A few questions here:

1. After `newCommandQueue` and similar functions should I retain object before return it?
2. I used `mdevice = (__strong id<MTLDevice>)device;` to cast void* to ObjC type, but what about this: `mdevice = device;`? It seems compiler does not complain.
3. For both in ARC and non-ARC it is safe to do casting between ObjC types and C void* as I did?

PS: My C functions are only wrappers to call ObjC functions from C. I'm not trying to access ObjC class members in C functions.

**EDIT:**

Release Code:

```
void
mtRelease(void *obj) {
  [(id)obj release];
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Updated Code (ARC disabled):

```
MtDevice*
mtDeviceCreat() {
  return MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
}

MtCommandQueue*
mtCommandQueue(MtDevice *device) {
  return [(id<MTLDevice>)device newCommandQueue];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calls to `-retain` are not correct in those two cases. `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` follows [the Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029), so it's already been retained for you. You are responsible for one (auto)release to balance the original creation, plus one for each `-retain` you perform.

Likewise, `-newCommandQueue` returns an object that's already retained and which you have to eventually release. [That's true of any method starting with "new"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).

`__strong` does nothing when ARC is disabled. `mdevice = device;` is fine.

Casting Objective-C object pointers to `void*` and back is "safe" (except for the loss of type safety). I recommend that you use pointers to opaque struct types instead of `void*`, to maintain type safety. For example, `typedef struct MtDevice *MtDeviceRef;`, where `struct MtDevice` is never defined. This is how Apple defines its own types, such as `CFStringRef`.

Comment: great answer! When using `typedef void MtDevice` compiler gives error when using this opaque type like this: `MtDevice device`, it compiles it with MtDeviceRef case. MtDeviceRef gives warnings with other types which is good of course, I may convert it to use struct later

Comment: Right. You wouldn't ever use `MtDevice` with my `struct` recommendation. You could use a different name for the typedef, of course.

Comment: I updated question to show release func. Wouldn't it enough to have single release call after `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` and `new or alloc/init`?

Comment: Yes, a single release is sufficient after `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` or a "new" method **if you don't do your own extra retain**. The non-ARC code in your question was doing an extra retain and then a single release is not sufficient.

Comment: as you said in your answer, I misused retain :) I'll remove extra **retain**s (without editing question)

Comment: I disabled ARC, removed extra retains and ugly __bridge casts, now codes are very clear/neat. I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: One additional thing to consider: you might want to follow the Core Foundation memory management naming conventions (i.e. use either "Create" or "Copy" in the name of a function which returns a +1 reference) or decorate your functions with `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED`. You may also need `CF_RELEASES_ARGUMENT` on the argument of `mtRelease()`. This will allow the static analyzer to properly analyze code which uses these functions.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, these will help me a lot. I'll make functions names similar, currently some of them uses **Creat** in name but I guess it is not enough, it should be Create (or Alloc/Make/New?). I definitely will use `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` and `CF_RELEASES_ARGUMENT`, good to know. What about `[commandQueue commandBuffer]` it returns autorelease-ed value (I guess): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandqueue/1508686-commandbuffer). Should I also annotate them with `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` or with something-else?

Comment: The Core Foundation naming conventions are different than Objective-C's, so "Alloc", "Make", or "New" don't mean anything special in a function name. Only use `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` on things which don't already conform to the naming convention. You need to figure out how you want to handle autoreleased objects in your C API. Will the client have an autorelease pool that it regularly drains? If not, you probably need to put autorelease pools of your own around the bodies of all of your methods and retain anything which needs to survive. In that case, you'd use "Create" or `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED`.

Comment: Actually it is not guarantee that there will be an autorelease pool. For instance if there is a metal surface which means that there is Cocoa or Cocoa Touch app, which means that there is always an autorelease pool (I guess). And pool will be drained with main run loop. Otherwise there may not be an autorelease pool. Maybe I should provide two version; one is autoreleased and other one is manually retained (like you described)